# Android development and TDD

Tags: java, android, tdd

Do anyone know of a good guide on how to do TDD (Test-driven development) with Android development? I'm interested in the mindset you should have before/during the creation of tests for activities.

I've only had one assignment earlier that had to be done through TDD (a bowling game). It gave me insights but Android development was far from what I was doing.

I'm starting to do a new SearchActivity, where I will be using the abstract BaseExpandedListAdapter class for my custom adapter class called ExpandableProfileListAdapterTest.

Now, for example how should someone go by doing a test for getGroupView and getChildView methods?

Answer (score 1):

The official Android documentation is very useful for producing tests for Android code: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals

Test-driven development is fundamentally the same for Android as any other kind of development, where you write your tests first and produce the source after, but it has a few differences as some systems to be tested must be mocked to prevent the need to fire up an emulator to test interaction based parts of the application.

[image]
Tests in Android consist of a 'pyramid' of tests, involving unit tests, integration tests and UI tests. These are separated because even though you may code a UI method for simply placing a button on a screen that is simple enough to be unit tested, it cannot be unit tested successfully if you want to assert that the button is placed as it will have to be run on an Android emulator (hence UI tests). To successfully create a clear line between what your unit tests are and integration tests, make sure that you're always refactoring and moving testable functional code to their own methods instead of including it in other UI-based methods (such as an application's onCreate).

Luckily, a lot of solutions exist to test all of these parts of Android. This [link to the article containing the image above](https://medium.com/android-testing-daily/the-3-tiers-of-the-android-test-pyramid-c1211b359acd) contains links to testing frameworks such as Mockito, Robolectric and Espresso for the different levels of Android testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I will look into this article that you mentioned... :)